# Field is member of a type which is serializable but is of type which is not serializable

Tags: c#, xml, serializable

I'm developing a C# library with .NET Framework 4.7.

I want to convert the class `ProductionOrderXmlFile` into a XML file:

```
[Serializable]
public class Level
{
    [XmlElement("Id")]
    public byte Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("CodeType")]
    public byte CodeType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("CodeSourceType")]
    public byte CodeSourceType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("HelperCodeType")]
    public byte HelperCodeType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("HelperCodeSourceType")]
    public byte HelperCodeSourceType { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("PkgRatio")]
    public int PkgRatio { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class VarData
{
    [XmlElement("VariableDataId")]
    public string VariableDataId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("LevelId")]
    public byte LevelId { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Value")]
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Class to load a production order from a xml file.
/// </summary>
[Serializable, XmlRoot("root")]
public class ProductionOrderXmlFile
{
    [XmlElement("ProductionOrderName")]
    public string ProductionOrderName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("NumItems")]
    public int NumItems { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("ProductCode")]
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("Reduction")]
    public float Reduction { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("Levels")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Level")]
    public List<Level> Levels { get; set; }
    [XmlArray("VariableDatas")]
    [XmlArrayItem("VariableData")]
    public List<VarData> VariableData { get; set; }
}
```

But in fields `public List<Level> Levels { get; set; }` and `public List<VarData> VariableData { get; set; }` I get the warning:

**Warning   CA2235  Field Levels is a member of type ProductionOrderXmlFile which is serializable but is of type System.Collections.Generic.List which is not serializable**

And:

**Warning   CA2235  Field VariableData is a member of type ProductionOrderXmlFile which is serializable but is of type System.Collections.Generic.List which is not serializable**

What do I need to do to avoid those warnings?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Lose the `[Serializable]`. Just throw it away - all of them. `XmlSerializer` doesn't care about it, and you don't need it. It isn't helping you, and is causing this false-positive warning.

`[Serializable]` relates *essentially* just to `BinaryFormatter`, which usually isn't a good choice.

Comment: Hey. What happened to the SOAPFormattter?

Comment: @bommelding that has been officially obsolete since .NET 2.0... and no, I don't mean .NET Core 2.0, I really mean .NET 2.0