# CA2235: Field is a member of type which is serializable but is of type which is not serializable .NET Standard

Tags: c#, serialization, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm porting a project from .NET framework (4.5) to .NET standard (2.0). The framework version of this section of code seems happy enough, but the standard section is giving me a the warning CA2235

It doesn't seem to matter if

1. It is an auto property, property with backing field or just a
   straight field
2. Whether or not it is readonly (i.e. whether or not it has a setter)
3. I have a 0 parameter constructor or not (sometimes relevant with serialization issues)

So in the code below:

```
[Serializable]
public class MyTestClass
{
    // "MyString" below produces Warning CA2235
    //    Field MyString is a member of type MyTestClass which is serializable but is of
    //    type string which is not serializable
    public string MyString { get; set; }

    // Field MyNullableInt is a member of type MyTestClass which is serializable but is of
    //    type int? which is not serializable
    public int? MyNullableInt { get; set; }

    //Both of the following seem to be OK
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
    public SomeEnum MyEnum { get; set; }
}

public enum SomeEnum
{
    One,
    Two,
    Three
}
```

In the searches I've done, it appears [this was fixed](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/1712).  I went to the project page and to the "Code Analysis" tab and installed the analyzer package which added a new NuGet package.

[image: NuGet packages]

I thought that would be all I needed to do to get the fix, but I guess not.  What am I still missing? (If it matters, I'm using VS 2019)

Before you refer me to [the post by Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50833829/1467396) let's assume I do need the `Serializable` attribute in my situation.  I'm more interested in why am still getting it if it was supposedly fixed?